# How can I customize the default name of home controller in MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I want to change the default Home controller name to new Customer controller. Can somebody explain what I should do ?

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Global.aspx.cs` there is a method like

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }
```

Here you can change the default controller name `Home` to `Customer`.
eg

```
new { controller = "Customer", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```